# change page according to ViewPagerIndicator listener

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using a library for viewpager indicators:
    `com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1`

I want to change the page showing on the viewpager according to which circle has been selected by the user.

How I can do this? 
Is there a way, or any library to achieve this?

```
    mPager = (ViewPager) headerView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)
            headerView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setFillColor(Color.parseColor(Keys.colorApp));
```

I want add to indicator ontouchlistener when user click on circle three then can change page to page 3
something like 
                mPager.setCurrentItem(pageNum, true);
but for indicator .

Comment: can you post some code of what have you done

Answer (score 0):

you can go to specific page by specifying the position of the pager

```
pager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

Comment: this to change page not to set listener to indicator